# BlackJack java random.nextInt

Tags: java, random, blackjack

```
public class BlackJack {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input;
        char reDo;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random random = new Random();
        int card1 = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int card2 = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int card = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int total1 = card1 + card2;
        int total2 = total1 + card;

        System.out.print("First cards: " + card1 + ", " + card2 + "\n");
        System.out.print("Total: " + total1 + "\n");

        boolean loop = true;
        while (loop) {
            System.out.print("Do you want another card? (y/n): ");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            reDo = input.charAt(0);
            if (reDo == 'y' || reDo == 'Y') {
                System.out.print("Card: " + card + "\n");
                System.out.print("Total: " + total2 + "\n");
            } else if (reDo == 'n' || reDo == 'N') {
                loop = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

> First cards: 8, 3
>   Total: 11
>   Do you want another card? (y/n): y
>   Card: 7
>   Total: 18
>   Do you want another card? (y/n): y
>   Card: 7
>   Total: 18
>   Do you want another card? (y/n): n

I want to be able to generate a new random card within the loop, display the recurring total, and stop the program. The issue I can't understand is how to use the random.nextInt tool and be able to reuse it more accessibly. Currently its stuck as card1, card2, card, total1, and total2. If I could make them so that I could access them more easily the program would be easier I think to write. The issue is that I can't understand how to repeat the random.nextInt within the while loop.

Comment: Can't you just call `card = random.nextInt()` as the first statement in the `if` body, before the two print statements?

Comment: I'm going to try this out, be back in a bit.

Comment: At some point you're going to want to create a deck of cards and "shuffle" it, and draw cards from it, rather than just rolling up cards randomly.

Comment: I commented out int card and int total2 from the top, and placed them both within the if statement. There is still an error and I'm not sure on what the next steps should be. Here is the output: First cards: 1, 3
Total: 4
Do you want another card? (y/n): y
Card: 2
Total: 6
Do you want another card? (y/n): y
Card: 9
Total: 13
Do you want another card? (y/n): y
Card: 7
Total: 11
Do you want another card? (y/n): n

Comment: @DavidConrad This is the third homework that's due for a second level Java class. I'm not quite sure how we would be expected to solve that much already. Although I'm retaking this course after withdrawing, I don't think the assignment is asking for that level yet.

Comment: No, don't move the `card` and `total2` variables into the loop, just update their values there. Notice that @jackarms suggestion didn't begin with `int`, just `card = random.nextInt()`.

Comment: Unrelatedly, this will give the wrong frequency of cards.  Value 10 is four times more likely than another value.  And aces are different.  But it's possible you were kind enough to remove that for your minimal example.

Comment: I tried to keep it the way @jackarms had mentioned in his comment, but the updates don't really make sense. It compiles but the program isn't making sense. Here is the output: First cards: 10, 2
Total: 12
Do you want another card? (y/n): y
Card: 7
Total: 19
Do you want another card? (y/n): y
Card: 6
Total: 19
Do you want another card? (y/n): y
Card: 1
Total: 19
Do you want another card? (y/n): y
Card: 9
Total: 19
Do you want another card? (y/n): n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First put all the cards in a deck.

Then generate a random number between 0 and the number of cards in the deck.

If deck is an ArrayList (for example), you could do

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
        deck.add(new Card(1));
        deck.add(new Card(3));
        deck.add(new Card(7));
        deck.add(new Card(10));

        Random randomGenerator = new Random(); 

        System.out.println("Deck 1 tests");
        // draw 3 cards:
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int randomCard = randomGenerator.nextInt(deck.size());
            Card card = deck.remove(randomCard);
            System.out.println("Removed a(n) "+card);
        }

        // you could also do
        List<Card> deck2 = new ArrayList<Card>();
        deck2.add(new Card(1));
        deck2.add(new Card(7));
        deck2.add(new Card(3));
        deck2.add(new Card(10));

        Collections.shuffle(deck2);
        System.out.println("Deck 2 tests");
        // draw 3 cards:
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Card card = deck2.remove(0);
            System.out.println("Removed a(n) "+card);
        }


    }

}

class Card {
    public Card(int i)
    {
        blackJackValue = i;
    }

    public int blackJackValue;

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(blackJackValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could understand this, but I think its too advanced for my abilities right now. We haven't gone over the ArrayList yet, and I think the Professor might get mad for me using work beyond my level.

Comment: I doubt it, since you'd be showing initiative. But if you want to use something more basic, have 2 arrays. One with the values and another one with a flag indicating if the value in the first array has been used or not.

Comment: I tried to input into the program that we're given for our school, but it won't compile properly. I recognize some of the work you just wrote. The ArrayList portion of the course is maybe a few weeks away, so I can't really submit it yet. Thanks for your help Alexandre!

Comment: Good luck. Most often than you'd imagine, in IT it is more important to be persistent than to be bright.